# drupal alter node edit form

Tags: drupal-7, hook-form-alter

How can I add a custom configuration area to a node edit form just beneath the **Authoring Information** & **Publishing Options** section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The follow code generates the last menu in the attached image:

```
    $form['barclays_epdq'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#access' => TRUE,
        '#title' => 'Barclays ePDQ',
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => TRUE,
        '#group' => 'additional_settings',
        '#weight' => 100,
        'barclays_epdq_active' => array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => 'Enable this webform to send users to your Barclays ePDQ store to make a payment',
            '#default_value' => $active_state,
        ),
    );
```

[image]

ps: the form is in hook_form_alter

Answer (score 14):

You can use  [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). 
Example below:

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  // if you are targeting a specific content type then 
  // you can access the type:
  $type = $form['#node']->type;
  // Then
  if ($type == 'my_content_type') {
  //  use a contact settings for the sake of this example
   $form['contact'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#title' => t('Contact settings'), 
    '#weight' => 100, 
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
   );
   // add simple checkbox to the field set
   $form['contact']['approve'] = array(
     '#type' =>'checkbox', 
     '#title' => t('Contact me'),
   );
  } 
}
```

**Now For storing the data** I encourage you to see the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) project; it has many code examples with lots of documentation. 
Also, Check [the Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/) for more information on different types of form elements.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input but I meant something like in my answer below:

Comment: You answer is identical to the one I provided.

Comment: Very identical but the location of the configuration area is what I was trying to achieve. You code worked without question but I was trying to achieve a different layout

Comment: Just a side note to the perfectly working code above: you may avoid conditional nesting by using a guard condition like this: `if ($type != 'my_content_type') { return; }`. Following code now is not nested (intended) which makes your code more readable.