# alter edit/create node form that pop ups in overlay

Tags: forms, drupal, alter

After digging a few months now in Drupal 7 and learned the basic concepts of the architecture i am stuck on something that looks pretty straight forward... .

I know how to alter forms that are in the website (such as the search form or the login form)... but i can't get it work to alter the node edit/create form (the one that shows up in the "overlay"... with the (custom)fields.

What i want to achieve is to change the default value of a select field when the form pops up in the overlay.

I tried the _form_alter(...) en also the admin theme seven_form_alter(...) hook but nothing gave the opportunity to alter the node edit/create form... . 
Can someone give me the right push to get back on track? 
Google didn't help me further on this one and am getting a little bit depressed... .

Links like these, i hoped helped but they didn't:
[drupal alter node edit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529636/drupal-alter-node-edit-form)

thx

Answer (score 0):

Hi The form alter should work irrespective of what the form is in Drupal. It will work for each and every form in Drupal provided you have give a proper condition to check the form id first.

One more suggestion. when you are trying form operations in Drupal disable the overlay module temporarily & then work on it..